# Don't work placeholders in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using this project (http://angular-google-maps.org/#!/) to work with AngularJS. I need consume the service ( service.latitude, service.longitude, service.id)

**app.js**

```
function ( $scope, markerService ) {
    var markerCollection = [];

    angular.extend($scope, {
      map: {
        control: {},
        center: {
          latitude: 33.5,
          longitude: -112
        },
        zoom: 10,
        fit: true,
        visible: true,
        pan: true,
        options: {
          navigationControl: true,
          scaleControl: true
        }
      }
    });


        var setMapMarkers = function (){
      var markers = {};
      var index = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.services, function (key) {
        var service = key.address;
        markerCollection.push(service);
        var serviceId = service.service.id;
        markers[index] = {
          "latitude": parseFloat(service.latitude),
          "longitude": parseFloat(service.longitude)
        };
        index++;
      });
      $scope.markers = markers;
    };
    setMapMarkers();    

 }
```

**index.html**

```
<div class='map-container' ng-controller='MapController'>
     <google-map center='map.center' draggable='true' pan='true' zoom='map.zoom'>
       <layer type='TransitLayer'>
         <marker coords='m' ng-repeat='m as markers'></marker>
        </layer>
    </google-map>
</div>
```

i dont know if my problem stay in the ng-repeat. Soomebody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ng-repeat should be "m in markers" not "as".

Without the markerService code it's not possible to see if you have other problems. You do have your developer console on right?

Comment: Thank you. that solve the problem :) rookie mistake :p